# How can I make a method return a "variable" (not value)?

Tags: java, user-interface, methods, global-variables, identifier

I have a set of global double variables called softPrice0 (and 1, 2, 3)

The thing is I had the idea to use a method like this:

```
SOMEWORD getOPrice()  //I tried double, String, Object, variable, etc
{return softPrice0;}
```

So I can use it later like this:
`getOPrice()=5.8;`

I know that using an array would do the trick but I would like to know if I can make methods throw variable names to use it as I explained.

---

thanks ortang

This is how I made it, the approach changed though.

```
setOPrice(Double.parseDouble(txtPriceDolar.getText())); //thats the call

void setOPrice(double value) { //this is the setter, no need of getter
switch(combobox.getSelectedIndex())
{case 1: this.softPrice0 = value; break;
 case 2: this.softPrice1 = value; break;
 case 3: this.softPrice2 = value; break;
default: this.softPrice3 = value; break;}}
```

now looks more simple, Thanks to everybody. Asking the wrong questions teaches a lot.

Comment: If it's global, why not just say `softPrecio0 = 5.8;` wherever you would use this function? Anyways, what you want to do is solved by using a "set" method-- pass `5.8` as the parameter to a function that does the actual assignment.

Comment: The thing is it is inside a bunch of switchs and ifs and it is not just one variable. The idea is that the method contains a switch that will select the right global variable so this can be assigned.
I couldn't follow you with the set. If you could please give me an example?

Comment: You don't have a global variable; this is Java. What you're describing sounds like a very bad design; if you can explain what it is you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to help.

Comment: okay there are 4 global variables softPrecio0,softPrecio2,softPrecio3,softPrecio4 all doubles. I want a method (probably a pair: setter, getter) to include a swicht(value) to assign the value to the right variable. something like ortang says i think. But i am trying to insert the "switch" part. I am trying not to use and array of double because this is part of an assigment and the variables were given. I can play with the methods as much as i want, i can do it manually but if i get the method do what i want it will be all more compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting you can not use the getter as you want to. `getOPrecio()=5.8;` will not work. You have to use a setter method. Take a look at the following sample, to access the value you have to use the getter(read) or setter(write).

You would want to use something like `setOPrecio(5.8)`.

```
public class DoubleHolder {
  private double vaule;

  public double getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value
  }
}
```

Comment: It finally compiled without errors. But I am not familiar with this and I don't know where to insert the switch so i can make the setter select between different global variables and set the value to it. But this seems very close, I am trying...

Comment: I think i managed with your answer. I will complete the evaluation and then share. (it seems the get value is not needed)

Answer (score 0):

Java passes by value, so this isn't possible without a separate getter and setter.

Examples:

```
void setOPrecio(double softPrecio0) {
  this.softPrecio0 = softPrecio0;
}

double getOPrecio() {
  return softPrecio0;
}
```

However, if the value is a class, you may be looking for something along the lines of the singleton pattern.

```
public class Singleton {
  private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

  private Singleton() {}

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Singleton example code from [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: okay... so i need to use both methods in different parts of my code to work it out? first the setter then the getter i guess... My id keeps telling me required: variable /  found:    value

Answer (score 0):

Java has no way of passing or returning a "variable".

The closest you are going to get are:

- passing or returning an object whose fields are the "variables", or
- passing or returning an array whose elements could be viewed as "variables".

And to be clear, neither of the contrivances are *close* to passing or returning a bare variable.

---

You need to rethink your problem / solution in terms of the constructs that Java *does* provide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was trying to push the limits, maybe I just pushed on the wrong direction. But Zach and ortang seem to have found a way.

Comment: In fact those solutions are my first bullet point.  As I said, it is not even close to "passing variables" ... or "pass by reference" as it is more commonly called.